# CiviMail Incomplete Load

Tags: civimail, joomla

I'm using Joomla 3.4.1 and CiviCRM 4.6.2.

When I click on Mailings > New Mailing, it's as if the component only partially loads. I have a menu bar with Search, Contacts, and Contributions; no other menu options. Below, I simply have the print icon and the version footer.

Is there a way to reinstall just the CiviMail component? I'm not an advanced user, so I don't even know where to start in trying to find out what's going on.

[image]

Comment: Did you just update? Try logout/login and if you aren't try as the super admin user

Comment: I updated a few days ago. Multiple log-ins and outs as the Super. No change. (Thanks for the quick response)